# Match all urls without the prefix in Django

Tags: python, django, django-urls

I'm currently using the following `urls.py`:

```
api_patterns = [
    url(r'^users/', include('users.urls', namespace='user')),
]

internal_patterns = [
    # ...
]

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^api/', include(api_patterns)),
    url(r'^internal/', include(internal_patterns)),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^(?!(?:api|internal|admin)/)', MainView.as_view()),
]
```

The point of this config is to render `MainView` if url doesn't have the `api`, `internal` or `admin` prefix:

- `/api/users/...` — found
- `/api/foo/` — not found
- `/foo/` — found

How can I make it simplier and more intent revealing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your intent will be more clear if you do this in two urls:

```
url(r'^(api|internal|admin)/', SomeView.as_view()),
url(r'^.*', MainView.as_view())
```

`MainView` will be executed only if a url does not begin with api, internal or admin.

`SomeView` will be executed if a url begins with api/internal/admin but doesn't match the patterns above it. You can customize this view to either return a default 404 page, or perform other functions as you need.

Using your examples:

- `/api/users` will execute `include(api_patterns)`
- `/api/foo` will execute `SomeView`
- `/foo` will execute `MainView`

**Edit**

To address the first point in your comment: url patterns are regexes, while you can extract these into variables to remove duplication, it can make code hard to read. Here's one example for removing duplication (I'm sure you can come up with others):

```
d = OrderedDict([
    (r'api', api_patterns),
    (r'internal', internal_patterns),
    (r'admin', admin.site.urls),
])

main_view_re = r'^!({})/'.format('|'.join(d.keys()))

urlpatterns = [url(r'^{}/'.format(k), include(v)) for k, v in d]
urlpatterns.append(url(main_view_re, MainView.as_view()))
```

Comment: First of all, that doesn't save me from repeating `api`, `internal` and `admin` twice. Second, rendering 404 by hand I lose that pretty django error page where it says “I tried this pattern and that pattern”.

Comment: I've updated the answer, please see if it addresses your concerns.

Comment: Yeah, I tried something like this, but as you can see it's even more obscure than before :) (though duplication is indeed removed)

Comment: At this point, adding comments to your code might be the best solution. I'm not sure if it is possible to remove code duplication while making the code simpler. Maybe you can try encapsulating more complex code in a function. Though with the updated solution, adding new url patterns which should be excluded from `MainView` is very easy.

Comment: Yes, creating functions with explicit names would be a good solution (much better than adding comments). I just want to be sure I don't miss something obvious reading the URL dispatcher docs.

Answer (score 1):

For **django >= 3** rather use **`re_path`**:

```
from django.urls import re_path

urlpatterns = [
    re_path(r'^.*',MainView.as_view())
]
```

Answer (score -2):

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^api/', include(api_patterns)),
    url(r'^internal/', include(internal_patterns)),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'', MainView.as_view()),
]
```

Leaving no prefix would allow you to catch any URL that a user might try after the URL conf matches the api, internal and admin url's.

Comment: But `/api/foo/` would be found, that's not what I want.